# East North Format

Tags: convert, latitude-longitude

I have a database with a list of address and their location as an East and North coordinate. An example is:
East=431833
North=336684
Postcode=DE22 4LF

When I try to convert this address using this tool:
http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/utm-latitude-longitude-d_1370.html

The result in longitude and latitude in Google gives me a location in Africa, not England where the address actually is.

Can anyone tell me which format the East and North coordinates are in and how to convert them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your coordinates are Ordnance Survey GB (OSGB36 Airy 1830 ellipsoid)
431833,336684 (base on a false origin with the Transverse Mercator projection.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid

To convert them correctly to Lat/Lng

Use this site:**http://www.nearby.org.uk**

example:
http://www.nearby.org.uk/coord.cgi?p=431833%2C336684
look for the result in yellow **Converts to 52.926628 -1.527923 (WGS84)**

copy and paste into google maps

https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=52.926628+-1.527923&hl=en&ll=52.926598,-1.5278&spn=0.00098,0.002792&sll=55.378051,-3.435973&sspn=15.177344,45.74707&t=m&z=19

You can also just use the postcode for google maps

https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=DE22+4LF&hl=en&ll=52.927293,-1.528076&spn=0.003919,0.011169&sll=52.926598,-1.5278&sspn=0.00098,0.002792&hnear=Derby+DE22+4LF,+United+Kingdom&t=m&z=17

Which returns the correct location - as is automatically geocoded into lat/lng coordinates

Comment: @Mapperz---how did you know the CRS!?

Comment: from experience

Comment: The presence of `postcode` is the tip, it seems.